# Django class based view related fields map url

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-class-based-views

I'm having trouble getting a Novel webpage to return a view with the appropriate chapters for a specific book. My index page lists all the objects of the Book model class and hyperlinks them to the detail page with the slug field.

```
<li><a href="{% url 'bible:detail' book.slug %}">{{ book.name }}</a></li>
```

This should call my detail.html page with the slug parameter (right???). The detail view works with the Chapter model class, which is linked to the Book model class with foreign key (id number). I realize the Chapter model class doesn't have a slug field of its own, but I think it should be able to map urls through the relationship to the book model. Is the a wrong assumption? I know I can add the slug field to the chapter model but it seems redundant since the application is a translator I will eventually make a model class for sentences in each chapter. How do I get this to work?
I don't know if my approach is even correct but this is the error I get:

```
TypeError at /novel/1984/

get_queryset() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'request' and 'slug'
```

The model consists of 2 classes (Book and Chapter) that are linked by foreign key (in Book). The book index page lists each of the books in library and hyperlink to their chapter index page. The book index page works fine however I am can't seem to properly pass parameters to chapter view and display the chapter index page (simply list the chapter number, which I would also hyperlink later). The code is a bit frankensteinish, if anything is unnecessary or if there is an easier way to do it please tell. Any help is greatly appreciated

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Book(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=33, db_index=True)
    short = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    search = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    chaptercount = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=33)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=33, verbose_name=('Book Slug'), default=name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Book, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['number',]

class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='chapters', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.book.slug, self.number)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('chapter_detail', [self.book.slug, self.number])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['number',]
        unique_together=(('book','number',),)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'novel'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<slug:book_slug>/', views.BooklistView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, UpdateView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Book, Chapter

class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'novel/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'lib_books'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Book.objects.all()

class BooklistView(ListView):
    template_name = 'novel/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'book_chapters'
    def get_queryset(self, request, slug):
        return Chapter.objects.filter(slug=book_slug)
```

index.html

```
{% if lib_books %}
    <ul>
    {% for book in lib_books %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'novel:detail' book.slug %}">{{ book.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No page available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

bookdetail.html

```
{% if book_chapters %}
    <ul>
    {{ chapter.book.title }} {{ book.number }} Chapters
    {% for chapter in book_chapters %}
        <li>{{ chapter.number }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
<p>No page available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `BooklistView(ListView)` rather be a `BooklistView(DetailView)`? I don't think you should need to overload the `get_queryset` method then. In the `novel/detail.html` you print your object with `{{ object }}`

Comment: I changed it to detail view, still wont load the page for the object. What do you mean by overloading the get_queryset?